# RequireJS, $.Deferred how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, require, amd, deferred

Following is the code

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
  var App = function () {
    var settings = {};
    var identity = {};

    var dSettings = $.when($.getJSON("models/settings.json"));
    var dIdentity = $.when($.getJSON("models/identity.json"));

    var dApp = $.when(dSettings, dIdentity);

    dSettings.done(function (data) {
      settings = data;
      console.log(settings);
    });

    dIdentity.done(function (data) {
      identity = data;
    });

    return {
      "settings" : settings,
      "identity" : identity
    };
  };
  return App();
});
```

I want to create a module, who can "know" my settings and identity.
Return will do before Deferred objects is resolved and module App.js have empty Settings and Identity objects.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/requirejs-promise

Comment: FYI, there is zero reason to use `$.when()` in this `var dSettings = $.when($.getJSON("models/settings.json"));`.  It can just be `var dSettings = $.getJSON("models/settings.json");`.  `$.getJSON()` already returns a promise which is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can get, you want the module to fetch your settings and identity data and return it as an AMD module. Unfortunately, you have an asynchronous operation there. The best you could do is to return a promise from the module instead and let the depending modules attach `then`.

```
// SettingsAndIdentity.js
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
  // $.when resolves when all promises passed resolves
  return $.when($.getJSON("models/settings.json"), $.getJSON("models/identity.json"))
});

// foo.js
define(['SettingsAndIdentity'], function(SettingsAndIdentity){
  // Since SettingsAndIdentity is a promise, we just attach then
  SettingsAndIdentity.then(function(settings, identity){
    // start doing things here
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't require.js allow modules to depend on json files?